# Full Screen On Multiple Monitors With XNA

Tags: xna, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I'm building a special application with XNA that is made for computers with multiple monitors.  The problem is that if I tell my XNA application to become fullscreen, it only covers the main screen.  How can I make sure that my application runs full screen across all of the screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't sound trivial at all. What happens when the screens are varying resolutions and aspect ratios? You'll have to create a rendertarget for each of the screens individually. There's no way to mesh them all into one giant rectangle reliably. Have a look at the [GraphicsAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsadapter_members.aspx) class, which should manage all of the graphics adapters available. I've never used multimonitor in a game but that's where I'd start. See if you can create multiple graphics devices or at least switch adapters between draw calls in order to render different targets to different screens.