# how to render from 2 cameras on 2 different screens, in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, multiple-monitors, multiscreen

my needs are to detect if there are 2 screens plugged in (and if not, program will exit), then, I'll let the user choose which screen is the front screen, and which is the back. finally, the game should have two cameras, each should render on a different screen (full-screen).
I've looked into [Full Screen On Multiple Monitors With XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081792/full-screen-on-multiple-monitors-with-xna) & [Working with multiple screens in XNA 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301020/working-with-multiple-screens-in-xna-4-0), which didn't quite helped with my needs. (the later has a broken link in the answer...)
what classes should i look into? is [`GraphicApater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197299.aspx) gives me all i need? maybe something else from the [`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.aspx) namespace?
thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Iv'e encountered [How do I ensure a form displays on the “additional” monitor in a dual monitor scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561104/how-do-i-ensure-a-form-displays-on-the-additional-monitor-in-a-dual-monitor-sc) and was thinking, if it's possible rather easily with forms, can i have a *"XNA form"*? I.E. a form, that has XNA content render onto it...
if so, i can just create 2 forms, make 'em load on different screens, and maximize (full screen) it. so, is it possible?

Comment: This is tricky. If I were going to try and do this, I'd study the details of how the WinForms sample works - particularly how it can present to multiple client areas. I think it can "sort-of" be done in XNA, but you might need DirectX to do it "properly".

Comment: @AndrewRussell do you know any resources that could get me "jump start" on this? i have very little experience with XNA, and C#. the only reason i'm doing this with C#, is because the project also make use of a kinect...